# If "header value" does not exist move to the next one?

Tags: vba

I need a quick advice (please see the code below). I would like the code to move on to the next line whenever the "header" for example for `("AW1")` doe not exist.

So e.g. the code encounters this line:

```
Col = Application.WorksheetFunction.Match(WS2.Range("AW1").Value, .Rows("1:1"), False)
.Cells(.Rows.Count, Col).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Resize(Rng16.Rows.Count).Value = Rng16.Value
```

If the `("AW1")` does not exist, I want it to do nothing at this point and instead to move on to the `("AX1")`:

```
Col = Application.WorksheetFunction.Match(WS2.Range("AX1").Value, .Rows("1:1"), False)
.Cells(.Rows.Count, Col).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Resize(Rng17.Rows.Count).Value = Rng17.Value
```

and so on, with each of them.

```
Sub TransData4Headers()

Dim WS1 As Worksheet
Dim WS2 As Worksheet

Dim Rng As Range, Rng1 As Range, Rng2 As Range, Rng3 As Range, Rng4 As Range, Rng5 As Range, Rng6 As Range, Rng7 As Range, Rng8 As Range, Rng9 As Range
Dim Rng10 As Range, Rng11 As Range, Rng12 As Range, Rng13 As Range, Rng14 As Range, Rng15 As Range, Rng16 As Range
Dim Rng17 As Range, Rng18 As Range, Rng19 As Range, Rng20 As Range, Rng21 As Range, Rng22 As Range

Dim Col As Long
On Error Resume Next

Set WS1 = Sheets("Main")
Set WS2 = Sheets("Bckg")

Set Rng = WS2.Range("AG2:AG2")
 Set Rng1 = WS2.Range("AH2:AH2")
  Set Rng2 = WS2.Range("AI2:AI2")
   Set Rng3 = WS2.Range("AJ2:AJ2")
    Set Rng4 = WS2.Range("AK2:AK2")
     Set Rng5 = WS2.Range("AL2:AL2")
      Set Rng6 = WS2.Range("AM2:AM2")
       Set Rng7 = WS2.Range("AN2:AN2")
        Set Rng8 = WS2.Range("AO2:AO2")
         Set Rng9 = WS2.Range("AP2:AP2")
          Set Rng10 = WS2.Range("AQ2:AQ2")
           Set Rng11 = WS2.Range("AR2:AR2")
            Set Rng12 = WS2.Range("AS2:AS2")
           Set Rng13 = WS2.Range("AT2:AT2")
          Set Rng14 = WS2.Range("AU2:AU2")
         Set Rng15 = WS2.Range("AV2:AV2")
        Set Rng16 = WS2.Range("AW2:AW2")
       Set Rng17 = WS2.Range("AX2:AX2")
      Set Rng18 = WS2.Range("AY2:AY2")
     Set Rng19 = WS2.Range("AZ2:AZ2")
    Set Rng20 = WS2.Range("BA2:BA2")
   Set Rng21 = WS2.Range("BB2:BB2")
  Set Rng22 = WS2.Range("BC2:BC2")

 With WS1

Col = Application.WorksheetFunction.Match(WS2.Range("AG1").Value, .Rows("1"), False)
.Cells(.Rows.Count, Col).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Resize(Rng.Rows.Count).Value = Rng.Value

 Col = Application.WorksheetFunction.Match(WS2.Range("AH1").Value, .Rows("1"), False)
 .Cells(.Rows.Count, Col).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Resize(Rng1.Rows.Count).Value = Rng1.Value

  Col = Application.WorksheetFunction.Match(WS2.Range("AI1").Value, .Rows("1"), False)
  .Cells(.Rows.Count, Col).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Resize(Rng2.Rows.Count).Value = Rng2.Value

   Col = Application.WorksheetFunction.Match(WS2.Range("AJ1").Value, .Rows("1:1"), False)
   .Cells(.Rows.Count, Col).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Resize(Rng3.Rows.Count).Value = Rng3.Value

    Col = Application.WorksheetFunction.Match(WS2.Range("AK1").Value, .Rows("1:1"), False)
    .Cells(.Rows.Count, Col).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Resize(Rng4.Rows.Count).Value = Rng4.Value

     Col = Application.WorksheetFunction.Match(WS2.Range("AL1").Value, .Rows("1:1"), False)
     .Cells(.Rows.Count, Col).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Resize(Rng5.Rows.Count).Value = Rng5.Value

      Col = Application.WorksheetFunction.Match(WS2.Range("AM1").Value, .Rows("1:1"), False)
      .Cells(.Rows.Count, Col).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Resize(Rng6.Rows.Count).Value = Rng6.Value

       Col = Application.WorksheetFunction.Match(WS2.Range("AN1").Value, .Rows("1:1"), False)
       .Cells(.Rows.Count, Col).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Resize(Rng7.Rows.Count).Value = Rng7.Value

        Col = Application.WorksheetFunction.Match(WS2.Range("AO1").Value, .Rows("1:1"), False)
        .Cells(.Rows.Count, Col).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Resize(Rng8.Rows.Count).Value = Rng8.Value

         Col = Application.WorksheetFunction.Match(WS2.Range("AP1").Value, .Rows("1:1"), False)
         .Cells(.Rows.Count, Col).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Resize(Rng9.Rows.Count).Value = Rng9.Value

          Col = Application.WorksheetFunction.Match(WS2.Range("AQ1").Value, .Rows("1:1"), False)
          .Cells(.Rows.Count, Col).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Resize(Rng10.Rows.Count).Value = Rng10.Value

           Col = Application.WorksheetFunction.Match(WS2.Range("AR1").Value, .Rows("1:1"), False)
           .Cells(.Rows.Count, Col).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Resize(Rng11.Rows.Count).Value = Rng11.Value

            Col = Application.WorksheetFunction.Match(WS2.Range("AS1").Value, .Rows("1:1"), False)
            .Cells(.Rows.Count, Col).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Resize(Rng12.Rows.Count).Value = Rng12.Value

           Col = Application.WorksheetFunction.Match(WS2.Range("AT1").Value, .Rows("1:1"), False)
           .Cells(.Rows.Count, Col).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Resize(Rng13.Rows.Count).Value = Rng13.Value

          Col = Application.WorksheetFunction.Match(WS2.Range("AU1").Value, .Rows("1:1"), False)
          .Cells(.Rows.Count, Col).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Resize(Rng14.Rows.Count).Value = Rng14.Value

         Col = Application.WorksheetFunction.Match(WS2.Range("AV1").Value, .Rows("1:1"), False)
         .Cells(.Rows.Count, Col).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Resize(Rng15.Rows.Count).Value = Rng15.Value

        Col = Application.WorksheetFunction.Match(WS2.Range("AW1").Value, .Rows("1:1"), False)
        .Cells(.Rows.Count, Col).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Resize(Rng16.Rows.Count).Value = Rng16.Value

       Col = Application.WorksheetFunction.Match(WS2.Range("AX1").Value, .Rows("1:1"), False)
       .Cells(.Rows.Count, Col).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Resize(Rng17.Rows.Count).Value = Rng17.Value

      Col = Application.WorksheetFunction.Match(WS2.Range("AY1").Value, .Rows("1:1"), False)
      .Cells(.Rows.Count, Col).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Resize(Rng18.Rows.Count).Value = Rng18.Value

     Col = Application.WorksheetFunction.Match(WS2.Range("AZ1").Value, .Rows("1:1"), False)
     .Cells(.Rows.Count, Col).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Resize(Rng19.Rows.Count).Value = Rng19.Value

    Col = Application.WorksheetFunction.Match(WS2.Range("BA1").Value, .Rows("1:1"), False)
    .Cells(.Rows.Count, Col).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Resize(Rng20.Rows.Count).Value = Rng20.Value

   Col = Application.WorksheetFunction.Match(WS2.Range("BB1").Value, .Rows("1:1"), False)
   .Cells(.Rows.Count, Col).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Resize(Rng21.Rows.Count).Value = Rng21.Value

  Col = Application.WorksheetFunction.Match(WS2.Range("BC1").Value, .Rows("1:1"), False)
  .Cells(.Rows.Count, Col).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Resize(Rng22.Rows.Count).Value = Rng22.Value

End With

End Sub
```

Comment: Does a header not exist if the cell has no value?  i.e. AW1 is empty.

Comment: Yes. When I say it doesn't exist, I mean the cell is completely empty (no formulas or format).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found an alternative that works. I have added this code, which essentially removes the line with piled up data (caused by inability of my initial code to ignore empty headers) and populates the empty cells in the last row of my aggregated table:

```
.Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Resize(.UsedRange.Rows.Count, 1).EntireRow.Delete
Sheets("Main").Select
LR = Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
Set Rg = Range("A" & LR & ":v" & LR)
For Each cl In Rg
If cl = "" Then
cl = "OK"
End If
Next cl
End With
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use an [if statement](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/language-reference-vba/articles/ifthenelse-statement?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) to conditionally execute code.

I've replaced the repetition in your code with a [for...next statement](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/language-reference-vba/articles/fornext-statement?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396).  There are several benefits to this:

- It improves the readability of your code
- It reduces the complexity of updating the code
- It reduces the number of required variables

Updated function:

```
Sub TransData4Headers()
    Dim WS1 As Worksheet
    Dim WS2 As Worksheet
    Dim currentRange As Range
    Dim currentCol As Long
    Dim Col As Long

    Set WS1 = Sheets("Main")
    Set WS2 = Sheets("Bckg")

    ' Column 33 = AG.
    ' Column 55 = BC.
    For currentCol = 33 To 55

        Set currentRange = WS2.Cells(2, currentCol)
        If currentRange.Value = "" Then

            Col = Application.WorksheetFunction.Match(currentRange.Offset(-1, 0).Value, WS1.Rows(1), False)
            WS1.Cells(WS1.Rows.Count, Col).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Resize(currentRange.Rows.Count).Value = currentRange.Value
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

Pressing F8 will execute the code one line at a time.  This is a great way to inspect the inner workings of the function.

Comment: Hi d-d, unfortunately I do not get any output on the bottom of data on Sheet(1).

Comment: I suspect I've butchered your logic while copying/pasting.  I made a small change to the line starting `Col = Application.WorksheetFunction...` which I may need to revisit.  Did you get this working?